# Convert varchar(255) to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't cast to convert data type varchar(255) to numeric

```
Amount
-1000
-500
-500,3827
-100,56
-1728,27781
```

What I did:

```
CAST([Amount] as decimal(10,4) as values
```

I get the error
    Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Is `-1728,27781` supposed to be `-1728.27781` (i.e. with a decimal point), or `-1728` and `27781` as separate values?

Comment: No, they are 1 value. -1728,27781

Comment: What RDBMS is this for?? If SQL Server: `decimal(6,4)` means a numeric value with a **total** of 6 digits, 4 of which after the comma (and therefore only max. **2** before the comma) - that's **not big enough** for 500.3827, for instance..... If you want 6 before and 4 digits after the decimal point, you need to use `decimal(10,4)` instead

Comment: @marc_s. I didn't know what that means because I tried to apply an example of the internet, but I will change it.

Comment: Just look [at the **official documentation** for `NUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - don't just rely on *some example from the internet* without checking official sources.....

Comment: I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

All of those values are too big for decimal(6,4).  Let's try a value that fits.
(Note: changing "," to "." for my locale)

```
DECLARE @MyVar varchar(255) = '-23'

SELECT CAST(@MyVar AS decimal(6,4))
```

which results in:

-23.0000

Fitting your longest (1728,27781) requires decimal(9,5):

```
DECLARE @MyVar varchar(255) = '1728.27781'

SELECT CAST(@MyVar AS decimal(9,5))
```

which results in:

1728.27781

From this you can see that the first number in the declaration represents the total number of digits, while the second number gives the decimals.  The decimal point itself is not part of the internal formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably:

```
select CAST(REPLACE([Amount], ',', '.') as decimal(10, 4))
```

Note:  Don't use `values` as a column alias.  It is a SQL keyword and a SQL Server reserved word.

Your problem is that you have bad values in the column.  You can avoid the error using:

```
select TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Amount, ',', '.') as decimal(10, 4))
```

You can find the problems using:

```
select amount
from t
where TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Amount, ',', '.') as decimal(10, 4)) is  null and Amount is not null;
```

Moral:  *Never* store numeric values in a string.

Comment: I have done it like this:     CAST(REPLACE([Amount], ' , ', ' . ') as decimal(10,4)) as decimalValues I still get the same error.